# Not letting graphics out of JFrame boundaries

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Although there are questions similar, I think mine is slightly different because of how I have my code set up. I have a JFrame within my main method. However, I only have JPanel in my constructor. I tried to make some of my variables static so that I could access them in the main method and say, for instance, if the x-coordinate of this graphic plus its width is greater than frame.getWidth().. but that won't work for some reason. I don't want to bombard anyone with code so I will just try to put the main information and if you need more, I'll update it.

```
   package finalProj;

   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class nonaMaingamePractice extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Ellipse2D ellipse;
    static Toolkit tools = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    static int screenWidth = (int)(Math.round(tools.getScreenSize().getWidth()));
    static int screenHeight = (int)(Math.round(tools.getScreenSize().getHeight()));
    private static Rectangle paddleRect;
    JLabel text = new JLabel("cool");
    Timer timeMove = new Timer(1, this);
    Timer timeBall = new Timer(10, new timeBall());
    private static double x = screenWidth/2, y = (screenHeight*0.8), xx = 0, yy = 0, score = 0, Ox = screenWidth/2, Oy = screenHeight/2, Oyy = 0, width = 100, height = 30;
    public  nonaMaingamePractice(){
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            timeBall.start();               
            timeMove.start();
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);

            JPanel panelNorth = makePanel();
            panelNorth.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + score);
            panelNorth.add(scoreLabel);


    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            paddleRect = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
            ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(Ox, Oy+Oyy, 50, 50);
            Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g;
            graphics.fill(paddleRect);             
            graphics.fill(ellipse);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x = x + xx;
            y = y + yy;

            if(x<0){
                    x=0;
                    xx=0;
            }


            repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int c = e.getKeyCode();
            if(c==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                    xx=1;
            }else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                    xx=-1;
            }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            xx=0;

    }
     protected JPanel makePanel() {
            @SuppressWarnings("serial")

                    JPanel pane = new JPanel() {

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 30);
                }
            };
            pane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            return pane;
        }

     protected class timeBall implements ActionListener{
         Timer timeWhateva = new Timer(100, this);

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try{
                        System.out.println(paddleRect.getX());
                        if(ellipse.intersects(paddleRect)){
                            timeWhateva.start();
                                Oy+=-1;
                                System.out.println(ellipse.getX() + " " + ellipse.getY());

                        }else if(!ellipse.intersects(paddleRect)){
                            Oyy+=1;
                        }
                }catch(RuntimeException NullPointerException){
                        System.out.println(NullPointerException.getMessage());
                }
                    repaint();
            }



     }


            public static void main(String[] args){

                    nonaMaingamePractice main = new nonaMaingamePractice();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(main);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setTitle("Project 4 game");
                    frame.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking how to make a JPanel with custom painting that is not larger than the screen?

Comment: Sorry @VGR, the question is: how can I make it so that the graphic does not leave the outside of the JFrame?

Comment: Remember, the frame's decorations are painted inside the bounds of the visible frame area, so, technically speaking, trying to confine anything to within the frame needs to take those things into consideration.  Having said that, I really have no idea what you're asking.  What graphics?  The simplest thing I can think of, is to simply use another `JPanel`, added to the centre position of the `BorderLayout` and use this to display any custom graphics

Comment: You also seem to be using multiple thread's which is kind of scary

Comment: Also, consider using `setExtendedState` instead of `setSize` to set the frames maximum size, it will take into consideration things like the task bar/doc, which would otherwise paint over the top of your window

Comment: @MadProgrammer what does that exactly mean "multiple threads," I assume that it has to do with the static variables. I wasn't sure if that was good practice or not. I can change them now because before what I was trying to do was access them in the main method because then I could get the frame width and adjust it to where the 2D rectangle I have does not go outside of the frame. That's essentially what I want to do. I have a 2D rectangle that I don't want to leave the from. I can stop it form going into negative numbers, but not from exceeding the width of the frame if I resize

Comment: Will you be drawing your graphics in a [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-) method, or do you plan to load an image and display it in a JLabel?  (Either way, your code should include an example of your approach.)

Comment: @VGR I've updated the entire code up there. I just didn't want you to have to sift through it all. I will be uploading an image, but also I have used the paintComponent to create an oval (ball) and a rectangle (paddle).. I don't have any helpful comments in the code right now because I am going to do that once I have finished.

Comment: Your ball and paddle should be limiting their positions based on the values returned when `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are invoked on the panel where the painting is done.  For example: Currently, you are checking for `if (x < 0)`.  To check whether the paddle has reached the right side, do `if (x + width >= getWidth())`.

Comment: Honestly @VGR I thought that I tried that, but apparently not. Thanks for the help. Could you give me advice on threads? What exactly does that mean? Is it bad practice? And will it affect the game?

Comment: Threads are multiple pieces of code that run at the same time. Swing does not allow multiple threads to interact with Components are the same time; everything must be done in one special thread, the AWT Event Dispatch Thread, to avoid any possible collisions or unpredictable behavior.  But Java invokes a `main` method in its own thread, not in the AWT even dispatch thread, so all of the code that's currently in your `main` method should be inside the `run()` method of a `Runnable`, which your `main` method should pass to `EventQueue.invokeLater` instead of invoking those lines directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96736/discussion-between-tyler-and-vgr).

Comment: @Tyler Actually, I took you `timeMove` and `timeBall` to be threads, which they aren't, but still, you should have a single "timer" or "game loop" or "main loop", which is responsible for updating the current state and schedule updates to the UI

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay, what would you suggest then if I need to have two separate timers. For instance, the timer for the 'timeMove' will be different than the timer for the 'timeBall'.. one is for the ability to move the rectangle, and the other will be physics related when I am ready. How could I make a single timer with different numbers of time?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there seems to a few things that are wrong.

First, don't rely on `static` for cross object communication, this is a really bad idea which will come back to bite you hard.  Instead, pass information to the classes which need it.

Second, I'd focus on having a single `Timer` (or "main-loop") which is responsible for updating the current state of the game and scheduling repaints.  This is the basic concept of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm

The first thing I'm going to do is take your code apart completely and rebuild it...

To start with, I want some kind of interface which provides information about the current state of the game and which I can pass instances of to other parts of the game in order for them to make decisions and update the state of the game...

```
public interface GameView {
    public boolean isKeyRightPressed();
    public boolean isKeyLeftPressed();
    public Dimension getSize();
    public void updateState();
}
```

This provides information about the state of the right and left keys, the size of the view and provides some basic functionality to request that the view update it's current state

Next, we need some way to model the state of the game...

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public interface GameModel {
    public Rectangle getPaddle();
    public Ellipse2D getBall();
    public void ballWasMissed();
}
```

So, this basically maintains information about the paddle and ball and provides a means by which the "main game loop" can provide notification about the state of the game back to the model

Next, we need to the actual "main game loop" or controller.  This is responsible for updating the state of the model and updating the view...

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class MainLoop implements ActionListener {

    private GameView gameView;
    private GameModel gameModel;
    private int ballYDelta = 1;

    public MainLoop(GameView gameView, GameModel gameModel) {
        this.gameView = gameView;
        this.gameModel = gameModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Rectangle paddle = gameModel.getPaddle();
        Ellipse2D ball = gameModel.getBall();
        // Update the paddle position...
        if (gameView.isKeyLeftPressed()) {
            paddle.x--;
        } else if (gameView.isKeyRightPressed()) {
            paddle.x++;
        }
        // Correct for overflow...
        if (paddle.x < 0) {
            paddle.x = 0;
        } else if (paddle.x + paddle.width > gameView.getSize().width) {
            paddle.x = gameView.getSize().width - paddle.width;
        }

        // Update the ball position...
        Rectangle bounds = ball.getBounds();
        bounds.y += ballYDelta;
        if (bounds.y < 0) {
            bounds.y = 0;
            ballYDelta *= -1;
        } else if (bounds.y > gameView.getSize().height) {
            // Ball is out of bounds...
            // Notify the gameView so it knows what to do when the ball goes
            // out of the game view's viewable, ie update the score...
            // Reset ball position to just out side the top of the view...
            gameModel.ballWasMissed();
            bounds.y = -bounds.height;
        } else if (paddle.intersects(bounds)) {
            // Put the ball to the top of the paddle
            bounds.y = paddle.y - bounds.height;
            // Bounce
            ballYDelta *= -1;
        }
        ball.setFrame(bounds);

        // Update the view
        gameView.updateState();
    }

}
```

This is basically where we are making decisions about the current position of the objects and updating their positions.  Here we check for "out-of-bounds" positions and update their states appropriately (for example, the ball can "bounce" and change directions)

The delta values are quite small, so you might want to play around with those

And finally, we need something that pulls it all together...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class NonaMaingamePractice extends JPanel implements KeyListener, GameView {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JLabel text = new JLabel("cool");

    private Timer timeBall;
    private GameModel model;

    private boolean init = false;
    private boolean rightIsPressed;
    private boolean leftIsPressed;

    public NonaMaingamePractice() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        JPanel panelNorth = makePanel();
        panelNorth.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + 0);
        panelNorth.add(scoreLabel);

        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0 && !init) {
                    init = true;
                    model = new DefaultGameModel(getSize());
                    timeBall = new Timer(40, new MainLoop(NonaMaingamePractice.this, model));
                    timeBall.start();
                } else if (model != null) {
                    model.getPaddle().y = (getHeight() - model.getPaddle().height) - 10;
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (model != null) {
            graphics.fill(model.getPaddle());
            graphics.fill(model.getBall());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            rightIsPressed = true;
        } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            leftIsPressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            rightIsPressed = false;
        } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            leftIsPressed = false;
        }
    }

    protected JPanel makePanel() {
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")

        JPanel pane = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 30);
            }
        };
        pane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isKeyRightPressed() {
        return rightIsPressed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isKeyLeftPressed() {
        return leftIsPressed;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateState() {
        // Maybe update the score??
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NonaMaingamePractice main = new NonaMaingamePractice();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(main);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Project 4 game");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```